# Proving this function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Define 
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
x/2 + x^2 \sin({1\over x}) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases} $$

I would like to show that $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and that $g'(0)>0$. My idea:

For $x \neq 0$ is is possible to compute the derivative: $1/2 + 2x \sin ({1 \over x}) - \cos ({1\over x})$. Therefore
$$g'(x) = \begin{cases}
1/2 + 2x \sin ({1 \over x}) - \cos ({1\over x}) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases} $$
The problem is: $g'(0)$ not $>0$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where does $g'(0)=0$ come from?

Comment: your assumption that $g(0)=0 \implies g'(0) = 0$ is invalid

Comment: $\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}=\frac{1}{2}+h\sin \frac{1}{h}$ so, the derivative exists at $x=0$, and equals $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $g$ is clearly differentiable on $\Bbb R^*$ and we have

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac12+x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac12>0$$

Comment: what happens to the cosine term? (when you differentiate $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$)

Comment: We have
$$0\le |x\sin\frac1x|\le x$$
so pass to the limit and use the squeeze theorem to get the result.

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^\ast$?

Comment: @blue $$\Bbb R^*=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$$

Comment: But $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, that is why the difference quotient at $0$ is checked next. In total, the function is continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R^*$ and differentiable on $\Bbb R$.